# onClick cardView it opens an intent with user custom data thats inside of selected cardView

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, android-intent, android-recyclerview

The app I am making is a workout log.I have a recyclerView with a popup dialog for user to a title for user routine. Once enter that goes to recycler cardView. What I am trying to do is when you click on the title it opens and you can write the list of workouts for that title meaning every title will have different data inside of them. I have set up onClick for the recyclerView but can not figure out how to do it where it open the data that was save to that title. How would I do so. I have looked on Stack Overflow for this answer and have not found it. I not working with a database right now so I know data will not save after app close

```js
public class WorkoutFragment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;





    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.workout_layout, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        setupRecyclerView(recyclerView);

        FloatingActionButton button = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab2);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                // Get the layout inflater
                LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

                // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
                // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fab, null);
                final EditText e = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.workoutTitle);
                builder.setView(v)

                        // Add action buttons
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(e.getText().toString())) {
                                    // This block is responsible for checking if editText is empty and carrying out the action
                                    onAddWorkout(e.getText().toString());
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // User cancelled the dialog
                            }
                        });
                // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();

                final Button positiveButton = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                e.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        positiveButton.setEnabled(s.length() > 0);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    private void onAddWorkout(String workoutTitle) {
        SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = (SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter) recyclerView.getAdapter();

       
        int length = adapter.mValues.length;
        adapter.mValues = Arrays.copyOfRange(adapter.mValues, 0, length + 1);
        adapter.mValues[length] = workoutTitle;
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(length);
    }


    private void setupRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),
                VersionModel.data));
    }

    public class SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        private String[] mValues;
        private Context mContext;

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            public final View mView;
            public final TextView mTextView;

            public ViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                mView = view;
                mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listitem_name);
            }

        }

        public String getValueAt(int position) {
            return mValues[position];

        }

        public SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, String[] items) {
            mContext = context;
            mValues = items;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.recyclerlist_item, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            holder.mTextView.setText(mValues[position]);
            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), RoutineListActivityTesting.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mValues.length;
        }
    }
}
```

﻿
This is my recyclerAdapter.

```js
public class SimpleRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleRecyclerAdapter.VersionViewHolder> {
    List<String> versionModels;
    Context context;

    public SimpleRecyclerAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public SimpleRecyclerAdapter(List<String> versionModels){
        this.versionModels = versionModels;
    }

    @Override
    public VersionViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.workout_layout, parent, false);
        VersionViewHolder viewHolder = new VersionViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SimpleRecyclerAdapter.VersionViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.title.setText(versionModels.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return versionModels == null ? 0 : versionModels.size();
    }

    class VersionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        CardView cardItemLayout;
        TextView title;

        public VersionViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            cardItemLayout = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardlist_item);
            title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.listitem_name);
        }

    }
}
```

This will be the intent but when it opens in the view I trying to have the custom user data listed that was associated with cardView title.

```js
public class RoutineListActivityTesting extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_routine_list);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.mToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView navView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        if (navView != null) {
            setupDrawerContent(navView);
        }
    }

    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                menuItem.setChecked(true);

                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
//                    case R.id.drawer_labels:
//                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
//                        break;
//                    case R.id.drawer_fab:
//                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
//                        break;
//                    case R.id.drawer_snackbar:
//                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
//                        break;
//                    case R.id.drawer_coordinator:
//                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
//                        break;
                }

                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            switch (id){
                case android.R.id.home:
                    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    } else {
                        drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    }

                    return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
```

The xml file that holds the titles

```js
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/cardlist_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listitem_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:text="Android version name"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text_default_material_light"
        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_subhead_material"/>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The is just random names recyler pulls just to fill in some space. Only posted this bit on code just in case you wanted to know what was the VersionModel in my other code. But would like to know if changing something in this code would it be usefully in helping with what I'm trying to do

```js
public class VersionModel {
    public static final String[] data = {
            "cupcake", "donut", "eclair", "froyo", "gingerbread",
            "honeycomb", "ice cream sandwich", "jelly bean", "kit kat",
            "Lollipop", "marshmallow"
    };

}
```

Comment: you can add your click listener inside adapter for row item than for recycler view

Comment: I am a noobie at this so I'm not sure how to do what you are saying.